# How do i implement link walking in Riak 2.0

Tags: riak

I am trying to come up one-many relationship where an user can have links to many  **organization** bucket.

I would like to walk and return the results back.

I am upgrading the stackmob's scala  driver to support linkwalking https://github.com/megamsys/scaliak

Any help would be greatly be appreciated. The forums talk about using mapreduce.

Comment: Thanks I found the answer here. http://basho.com/link-walking-by-example/

Answer (score 4):

Link walking is [deprecated in the latest version of Riak](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/link-walking/), and will likely be removed in future versions. So it probably doesn't make sense to upgrade the Scala driver to support it.

The real question here is - how should you model a One to Many relationship in Riak? There are two main approaches to this, depending on if you have a read-heavy or a write-heavy use case.

**1 - Links as Lists of Keys**

You can store the list of links/associations as a separate object for easy retrieval. For example, if I have a users object stored at `/buckets/users/keys/user-id-123`:

`{ id: "user-id-123", name: "Dmitri", ... }`

I can then store the organizations that user belongs to (notice that I'm using the same key for the user and for their membership object) in `/buckets/user-orgs/keys/user-id-123`:

`["organization-id-1", "organization-id-2", "organization-id-3"]`

This allows me to answer the question of "Which organizations does this user belong to?" with a single GET to the `user-orgs` object (and, optionally, a multi-get to fetch each of the organization objects by their IDs).

Note: If you're using Riak 2.0 or above, you can use the new [Riak Data Types](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/theory/concepts/crdts/) (specifically, the [sets](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/dev/using/data-types/#Sets) data type), to store that list of IDs. (The Sets data type provides an API of operations to add/remove/fetch elements from a list in a way appropriate for distributed systems).

Use this approach when you have a read-heavy use case (when the list of links is read frequently, but is not written to/updated frequently).

**2 - Search / Query for the links**

The other main approach is to use indexes (preferably via the Solr-based [Riak Search](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/dev/using/search/), or, for rare cases, via [Secondary Indexes](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/dev/advanced/2i/)) and queries to retrieve one-to-many association objects.
So, if you had a user object stored at `/buckets/users/keys/user-id-123`:

`{ id: "user-id-123", name: "Dmitri", ... }`

You would then insert multiple "membership entry" objects into the [search-enabled](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/dev/using/search/#Simple-Setup) (meaning, you would create a search index and associate it with the `user-orgs` bucket) `/buckets/user-orgs/`:

`{user_id: "user-id-123", org_id: "organization-1"}`

`{user_id: "user-id-123", org_id: "organization-2"}`

`{user_id: "user-id-123", org_id: "organization-3"}`

Afterwards, you can answer the question "Which organizations does the user belong to?" by issuing a Search query saying "Give me all of the objects in `user-orgs` where `user_id` equals to `user-id-123`", for example.

Incidentally, using Search / membership objects like this also allows you to model a Many-To-Many relationship (meaning, you can *also* answer the question "Which users belong to the organization `organization-id-1`?").

Because Search queries are more expensive than a single GET to fetch a membership list (like in the first strategy), you should use this strategy when you're not in a read-heavy use case (when the membership objects are updated often, but not read often), or when you need to also model the inverse relationship (many to many).

**Note:** Do *not* use Map/Reduce to model one-to-many relationships, and don't use the deprecated Link Walking mechanism (which uses Map/Reduce on the backend, anyways).